# dependencies in pom file

Tags: java, pom.xml

Please, explain,

I try to add jstl. I do everycing according manual. But jstl still remains red.

> ```
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
>         <version>1.2</version>
>     </dependency>
> ```

and jstl and 1.2 becane red and server gives me a error.

May be I did soethign wrong. There is no higher viersion....

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is your server ? What is your error message ? Tomcat version ? WAR ? Jakarta EE version ? Spring Boot Version ?

Comment: "it becomes red" implies an IDE is telling you that. What happens when you run `mvn install` ? In IntelliJ for example you need to hit a button before it will download any new artifacts that you added to the pom so until you do it will claim that the artifact does not exist.

Comment: Try to google maven jstl, then goto https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl and copy-pasta. You've using a real old manual.

Comment: Thank you all. I really appreciate your help. I wil try each proposal.